# Can you convert blend to simple vector shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shadows, blending

I am finishing graphics for my settlement plan and I am having some issues with shadows. Basicly all I wanna do is just move objects about 4 meters in 45° angle. Is there a way to make a "step" free blend and expand to one shape so I can manipulate appearance easier or any way to make simple shape?

[image: I made 250 step blend to make shadows][image: is there a fast way to make shape like this?]

Answer (score 4):

You could expand the blend (<kbd>Object</kbd> > <kbd>Expand Apperance...</kbd>), ungroup it and then unite all shapes in it into a single shape using the Pathfinder palette. If you then give that shape a gradient fill, you should have your effect.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` ▶ `Blend` ▶ `Expand` will turn all the intermediary blends into normal paths. From there, as @Vincent suggests, you can use the Pathfinder palette (`Window` ▶ `Pathfinder`) to Unite or Merge them as you might like.